# Algorithm for splitting rent

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone come up with an algorithm for splitting rent for an apartment with bedrooms of wildly disparate quality?

The constraints, I believe, are:

- the total rent for all bedrooms (In my case, three, but possibly any number) sums to the total apartment rent.
- the subjective value curves of each resident regarding room quality vs cost
- the "consumer surplus" (ie, the disparity between how much the resident would be willing to pay and the amount they are paying) of each resident is as close to equal as possible:

Obviously, this is a poorly constrained problem, but any help getting closer to an equitable answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your best shot so far?

Comment: The problem is not unsolvable, so yes, such an algorithm exists.

Comment: How do those "subjective value curves" look like?

Comment: How about **`cost / number_of_renters`**?

Comment: why is there a need to be subjective? is one room re-painted but the others are not? i would base a rooms rent on the area of the room in proportion to the entire apartment, ie: rent for room A = (room A area / total apt area which is not common space)*(total apt rent)

Comment: Re: closed -- what is a "fact"?

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced this problem. I have found that the simplest solution is to take an empirical approach: use bidding. Carry out a bidding process whereby people bid by increasing their rent past the average in order to take a room.

If there are multiple rooms of interest, it is useful to allow people to change their bids as other room prices change. Hopefully, eventually, the bidding will come to an equilibrium.

Each individual's rent can be normalized after the bidding process.